# Is it possible to Execute Pipelines using a JSON file in ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

We have 70 SAP tables to load and we are currently running 1 pipeline that executes 1 Pipeline to each of the tables (each contains only one copy data).

In the past, I managed to run Databricks Notebooks by creating a JSON file with just the notebook name and path.

To do that I created a Lookup Activity in my ADF Pipeline to check the JSON file and a ForEach with a Notebook activity connected to my Databricks connection.

I was trying to do the same for different pipelines that I have with Copy Data activities but the Execute Pipeline activity doesn't allow Advanced Expressions like the Notebook activity (image bellow)

[Notebook and Execute Pipeline Activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r7z7.jpg)

Any ideia how I can execute multiple pipelines in one simple process to make ADF pipeline look cleaner and make it easier to make changes?

Comment: You might be better off looking at a metadata driven pipeline using ADF, same concept:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/get-metadata-driven-data-ingestion-pipelines-on-adf-within-10/ba-p/2528219

Comment: Hi, any update of this?

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu-MSFT, I haven't had time to get back to this issue yet

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu-MSFT, sorry for the delay. I managed to do what I wanted by applying the explanation of this link: https://www.richardswinbank.net/adf/parameterising_the_execute_pipeline_activity